# Error when installing latest Android SDK on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Tags: android, linux, sdk

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. I downloaded the android adt from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html:

[image]

Download the `android-sdk_r21.1-linux.tgz` 64-bit Linux distro and extract it:

[image]

Then run the **Android SDK Manager** directly from the command line:

[image]

Install Android Tools and the latest Android flavor:

[image]

**Error!**:

[image]

But ADB *is* there! I swear!:

[image]

And the emulator **doesn't even start**:

[image]

What is the cause of the ADB "Can't run program" error, and why can't I start the emulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the `ia32-libs` package through apt. The file not found is a bit misleading, but it's basically what happens if you try to run a 32-bit binary without 32-bit support.

Comment: Thanks @FatalError (+1) - I'll give it a try - do I need to uninstall/reinstall anything in the Android SDK Manager?

Comment: You shouldn't need to, ideally it will just work afterward (it worked for me when I had the same issue).